# converting oracle query to hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

The query below gives me the minimum and maximum times of a users transaction on each date in a date range. 
 The table user_transaction I have is a domain class. I want to write the query below using hibernate (hql or hibernate criteria builder for grails)

```
select (MIN(TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS'))) AS TIME_IN,(MAX(TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS'))) AS TIME_OUT, TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE,'DD-MM-YY') from user_transaction where grauser_id=149180 and transdate BETWEEN '01-NOV-11' AND '31-DEC-12' 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE,'DD-MM-YY')
```

Also need to find the avg timein and timeout

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will probably want to look for the [Criteria api](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objecstate-querying-criteria), and [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection).  Projections are the group by equivalent in a criteria query.

The Projects.sqlProjection("") is also available to support your to_char situation.